# Docker volume is not synced

Tags: docker, volume

I have a "weird" issue with Docker.

I have a PHP container, running a web app where we can upload files.
The problem is: When I upload a file, the file is present in the host volume but isn't in the "target volume"...

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
php:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
        - ./app/:/usr/src/app
    restart: on-failure
    user: 1000:1000
    environment:
        APP_ENV: dev
        APP_DEBUG: 1
        SECRET: fezfze954fze564fze1z51fze546fe
        DB_USER: ff
        DB_PWD: 48zef5ze1f45ze1f45ze6
        DB_NAME: ff
        DB_VER: mariadb-10.4.12
        DB_PORT: 3306
        GRECAPTCHA: 1f65ze1fze61fze65f1ze651fze65fze
        MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC: fe65fze165efz165fze16f5ez16f5ze
        MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE: f495ez4fez561fze561fz6e515fze
        MJ_EMAIL_DEFAULT: fezfezy@ffzefezfez.com
```

And the dockerfile:

```
# ./docker/php/Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

#OPCACHE
RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
COPY docker/php/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

#PHP Config
COPY docker/php/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN pecl install apcu

RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
zlib1g-dev

RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
COPY --chown=33 app/ /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/apps/vendor/bin:bin
```

## EXAMPLE1:

I upload a document trough my web app.
The document is visibile on me IDE (PhpStorm) in the web app
If I do a docker exec -it container bash and I go to the web app I see it
BUT, if I go trough my browser, I do not see it and I still see old files.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Docker volume does not like trailing slash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583900/mounted-volume-is-empty-inside-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mounted volume is empty inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583900/mounted-volume-is-empty-inside-container)

Comment: Hello :)

No... I realy don't know why..

Comment: I just added an example

Answer (score 0):

I just find why: the file permissions are set to root... (so unreadable publicly)
But, I have the "user: 1000:1000" directive so why it get root ?