# Permission denied, cannot open static files, Docker, Django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, django-staticfiles

I am new in docker, I want dockerize my django application to production.
My OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS,
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88,
My docker-compose.yml file as below:

```
version: '3.1'

services: 
    nginx-proxy:
        image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
        restart: "always"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
            - ./nginx/vhost/:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:ro
            - ./nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/client_max_body_size.conf:ro
            - ./static/:/amd/static
            - ./media/:/amd/media
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6.6
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./pgdb/:/var/lib/postgresql/
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        env_file: ./.env

    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        restart: always


    web:
        container_name: amd
        build: .
        restart: "always"
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/code/ 
            # - ./static/:/code/static
            # - ./media/:/code/media
        depends_on:
            - "postgres"
        env_file: .env

    celery:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: celery.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        command: celery -A amdtelecom worker -l info   
        links:
            - redis
            - postgres
        depends_on:
            - "redis"
            - "postgres"
        env_file: ./.env

networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: nginx-proxy
```

My Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBUG False

COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . .

CMD [ "gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8000",  "amdtelecom.wsgi" ]
```

in my project setting file:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost"
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if PROD:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        BASE_DIR / "static",
    ]
    
    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

SITE_URL = 'http://localhost:80'
```

I use the below steps in my terminal:

1. docker-compose up -d --build
2. docker ps -a
3. docker exec -it 'my gunicorn id' bash
4. ./manage.py migrate
5. ./manage.py collectstatic
6. ./manage.py loaddata data.json

and open try open project in chrome browser in url **localhost**
and project opens without static files (no js, no css).
[image: This is how it opens in the browser]
And in my docker logs:

```
> (docker-compose logs -f):
2021/03/25 10:51:32 [error] 51#51: *18 open() "/amd/static/images/fashion/product/13.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.23.0.1, server: localhost, request: 
"GET /static/images/fashion/product/13.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"
```

[image: docker logs]
*and I want one note about my code - this application already work fine in Mac OS, static files open fine. I think my problem is related with my Linux OS.*

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance. For additional information about my code it is [github repo](https://github.com/fuadsuleyman/amd):

Comment: I checked your repo. In your Docker-compose file in the volumes you use `./static/:/amd/static` and `./media/:/amd/media`. But I cannot find the amd folder there. Is the path correct?

Comment: Try synchronizing trailing slashes in volume mounts as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583900/mounted-volume-is-empty-inside-container

Comment: @ctwx thanks for comment, but I try that method, but can't achieve any positive results. I want one note about my code - this application already work fine in Mac OS, static files open fine. I think my problem is related with my Linux.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thanks for help in my question editing, I change that trailing slashes but get same errors. I want one note about my code - this application already work fine in Mac OS, static files open fine. I think my problem is related with my Linux.

Comment: Check directory permissions then.

Comment: @IvanStarostin my static and staticfiles diroctory was - **drwx------ 14 fuad fuad  4096 Mar 19 03:26 static** , **drwx------ 15 fuad fuad  4096 Mar 19 03:26 staticfiles** , I change him, now -  **drwxrwxrwx 14 fuad fuad  4096 Mar 19 03:26 static** and **drwxrwxrwx  14 fuad fuad  4096 Mar 19 03:26 staticfiles** . but I had same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably dwells in permissions, more exactly in file owners - you can solve it easily (but not much securely) with `chmod 777` on all files in the static (or media) volume.

The second option is to chown to the container user as decribed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910717/7113416 or propably even better here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56904335/7113416