# Cannot see my volume in the container of CentOS

Tags: docker

here's my docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
      - ./:/home/admin
```

i can see my files in the docker container from my laptop (MacOS)
but when i deploy it in my docker of CentOS
/home/admin is empty

Comment: Are you expecting to have the same files on your laptop and on a server for a bind mount ?

Comment: expecting to have same files between my CentOS and its container

Comment: you mean that the container has no files in `/home/admin` but `./` on CentOS has some ?

Comment: yes, and i tried to do same thing on my MacOS, it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mounted volume is empty inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583900/mounted-volume-is-empty-inside-container)